# Django: Form in your Site Base template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-middleware

I need to create a form, not search, but a kind of profile switcher that will be present in the site base.

Just wondering what's the best way of going about this? I'm not very familiar with middlewares but this sounds like the time to investigate it?

Alternatively, I was thinking I could load the form from a templatetag?

I'm just looking for different ways to implement this site wide form. Thanks.

A good example would be Github. The switch account context gives you different pages/accessibility based on your current account context.

Comment: i don't think i fully understood your question: what do you mean by "profile switcher"? how does the user interact with that form of yours? are you trying to change the displayed form or the result after the switch process?

Comment: A user can have many profiles and depending on which one he selects, he gets access to different things.

Comment: then it's like what drtyrsa said. basically, suppose you have a "profile1", "profile2", "profile3" values. user selects profile1. You send the "profile1" value inside a variable via the context processor (as pointed out by tyrsa). Then, in your html you can do something like {% if variable=="profile1" %} <stuff to display for profile1 {% endif %} and so on for the other 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a template including a form, and include this template in your base.html. You have access to the user profile in the template via

```
{{ request.user.get_profile }}
```

It this what you need?